# Access component provider from child component through ng-content

Tags: angular

I am using the library [ngx-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl). The library provides a component, "mgl-map", which lets you add child layer components which then render on the map.

My goal is to have a parent component which houses the map component, and let the layers be injected using ng-content.

```
Inside custom map component map.component.ts:
    <mgl-map ...>
      <!-- layers will be injected here -->
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mgl-map>


Intended use of app-map component:
    <app-map>
      <some-layer ...></some-layer>
    </app-map>
```

This throws the following error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LayerComponent -> MapService]:
```

I believe that the issue stems from the use of a component provider in the library's [map component](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl/blob/master/projects/ngx-mapbox-gl/src/lib/map/map.component.ts) where the MapService is provided.

This problem has been noticed by other users, but the project maintainer has not provided an example of where this could work yet: https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl/issues/51. The suggested fix is to use dynamic content injection.

**My attempt to fix this**

I have tried using an ng-template in the parent component and an ng-container with ngTemplateOutlet for dynamic content injection as the maintainer suggested, but this does not work, yielding the same error. Example:

```
app.component.html:
    <app-map [layers]="layers">
      <ng-template #layers>...</ng-template>
    </app-map>

map.component.ts:
    @Input() layers: TemplateRef<any>;

map.component.html:
    <mgl-map ...>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="layers"></ng-container>
    </mgl-map>
```

The child components can still access the parent mgl-map component by injecting the host, so I am not sure exactly why the provider cannot also be referenced.

How can I force the child components to use the MapService from the correct parent component, or is this impossible?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mind building a small reproduction (say, using stackblitz)? I'll try to see what we can do here (i'm current de-facto maintainer of the project).

Comment: @DmytroGokun Here is a simple StackBlitz demo of layers not working through ng-content: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mapbox-gl-ng-content

Comment: Looks like you either forgot to save your changes in the stackblitz or it is not correct. I get this error when opening it: 

"Error in src/styles.css
Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/dev/null'"

Comment: Should be working now. StackBlitz seems a bit temperamental with CSS imports apparently.

Comment: Yep, i was able to reproduce it. I will look at it and see if I can invent anything. If you have some ideas how to fix this - do not hesitate to let me know :)

Comment: The best solution I can think of is moving everything from map.service.ts into map.component.ts. Then map.component.ts should use an ng-content to inject content rather than the current approach of layers injecting the service. Layers can then access the map by injecting the host component instead of the service into the layers.
It's a huge refactor.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that will work. But that is a huge refactor. Not sure if it's worth it. Have you managed to find a work-around?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218291/discussion-between-matthew-evans-and-dmytro-gokun).

Answer (score 0):

Their are 2 places where you can provide service -

1. In app module
2. In map compoments provider array

In map component provide service like -

```
import mapService from 'mypath';

@Component({
   ....,
   providers:[mapService]

})
```

Comment: The MapService service is private in the ngx-mapbox-gl and when it is instantiated I think it is injecting the mgl-map component to itself, so I cannot pass the injectable manually it seems.